# Progress Bar 100% on load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make progress bar for my one-page website and everything works fine and how I want except when page is load progress bar is on 100% not on 0% until I start scroll. This is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="progressContainer">
    <div id="progress" class="progress"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.progressContainer{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}

.progress{
    height: 10px;
    background: #D66A00;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function updateProgress(num1, num2){
    var percent = Math.ceil( num1 / num2 * 100 ) + '%';
    document.getElementById('progress').style.width = percent;
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    var top = window.scrollY;
    var height = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height - window.innerHeight;
    updateProgress(top, height);
});
```

DEMO

https://codepen.io/Klak031/pen/xdXYgb/

Comment: well it's just that .progress element inherits the width from parent so it's 100% at start, change it to 0 in the css declaration

Comment: .progress{width:0%;} just add this to your css

Comment: That works :) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just a small glitch in css can do the fix.** Add `width:0%` to your `progress class` and you are good to go.

```
.progress{
    height: 10px;
    background: #D66A00;
    border-radius: 0;
    width:0%;
}
```

Here is the Updated codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmBXXB

Comment: 0 and 0% is one and the same thing @monas

Comment: That is what I'm saying ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not set the width of your progress class, it will be set default to auto and will fill out the parent element, in this case the progressContainer class, which has a width of 100%.

```
.progress{
    height: 10px;
    background: #D66A00;
    border-radius: 0;
    widht: 0;
}
```

I hope it helped understanding the solution to your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use different function on ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  updateProgress(0, 100);
});
```

[Edited Codepen](https://codepen.io/monasLT/pen/oWGEoz)

Update: actually there is no need to do anything on document ready, my bad. Setting

```
.progress { width: 0;}
```

will do the trick.

Comment: If you look closely, this makes "flashing" effect which on slower computers will be extra visible, initial state should not be manipulated by JS for better UX.